# Pandas mark all rows for a column which is inbetween two different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns:

1. Start
2. End
3. Continue

**What I am trying to do:**

> Based on ***Start*** flag and ***End*** flag columns I need to apply 1 to the in-betweens in ***Continue*** Flag column.

**What I did:**

> I tried by iteration of *start* column and finding the first occurrence of *end* column from the next index and used the indexes to apply 1's to Continue.

**The issue:**

> But since I used a traditional *for  in container* loop it was very slow and I have a huge dataset.

Is **df.apply()** possible ?

Below is the sample input and my code.

**Input Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'START': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                        'END': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] ,
                        'CONTINUE': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
                        })
```

**My Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'START': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                        'END': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] ,
                        'CONTINUE': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                        })

for first in dataset[dataset['START'] == 1].index.values:
    last = dataset.loc[first+1:,'END'][dataset.loc[first+1:,'END'] == 1].index.values[0]
    dataset.loc[first+1:last-1, 'CONTINUE'] = 1
```

**Visual Input Repr.:**

```
    START  END  CONTINUE
0       0    0         0
1       1    0         0
2       0    0         0
3       0    0         0
4       0    0         0
5       0    0         0
6       1    1         0
7       0    0         0
8       0    0         0
9       0    1         0
10      0    0         0
11      1    0         0
12      0    0         0
13      0    0         0
14      0    1         0
```

**Expected Output Repr.:**

```
    START  END  CONTINUE
0       0    0         0
1       1    0         0
2       0    0         1
3       0    0         1
4       0    0         1
5       0    0         1
6       1    1         0
7       0    0         1
8       0    0         1
9       0    1         0
10      0    0         0
11      1    0         0
12      0    0         1
13      0    0         1
14      0    1         0
```

Comment: looking at the output, it seems if ``START`` and ``END`` are both ``0``, then ``CONTINUE`` should be ``1``. is that logic flawed?

Comment: @sammywemmy There isn't any math involved in this data. It's just that the data is that way. These are real world data that I have marked with the start and end behaviour and I am trying to track the behaviour continuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `cumsum`

```
df['CONTINUE']=(df.START.cumsum()-df.END.cumsum())-df.START
df
Out[96]: 
    START  END  CONTINUE
0       0    0         0
1       1    0         0
2       0    0         1
3       0    0         1
4       0    0         1
5       0    0         1
6       1    1         0
7       0    0         1
8       0    0         1
9       0    1         0
10      0    0         0
11      1    0         0
12      0    0         1
13      0    0         1
14      0    1         0
```

Comment: You sir are a legend. This was the fastest solution I have recieved so far. Thanks a lot. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: @High-Octane happy coding ~

Answer (score 1):

**df.apply()** is possible.

Consider this approach:

```
between = False        
def row_modifier(row): 
  global between       
  if row.END:
    between = False    

  if row.START:        
    between = True     

  if not row.START  and not row.END and between:
    row.CONTINUE = 1   

  return row 

dataset.apply( row_modifier, axis = 'columns' )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Mark, Your solution was great but it took me 10 mins to complete. I think it's due to me having a lot of columns in my dataset. I think I can fix that by listing my 3 columns alone and apply. It's been a great help. I'll try that as well.